# Image not showing with Flask HTML CSS background image

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm trying to set a background image using Python3 with Flask.

My Python file looks like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static/', static_folder='/static/')

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
  return render_template('index.html')
```

The HTML block includes:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
  <!-- Bootstrap 4 beta -->
     <link rel="stylesheet"...
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bg-logo">
        col 1
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And my CSS file:

```
.bg-logo{
  background: url({{ url_for ('static', filename = '/static/img.png') }});
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

For some reason, the browser can't get to the CSS file correctly. I need a way to serve the static files from the static folder without a @app.route

Comment: `static_folder='/static/'` looks suspicious. Could you please check that this is the correct folder location within your filesystem?

Comment: I use PyCharm and the link was valide, I tried 'static/' before as well and wasn't able to validate it

Comment: I removed the static folder as suggested by @afc11hn as well and that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I have same problem with you. After looking several answers, this will help you.

Make sure you organized your files like this:

```
/app.py
/static/main.css
/static/img.png
```

In app.py (or whatever your flask filename), just do as @afc11hn say:

```
app = Flask('__name__')

...
```

Then in main.css:

```
.bg-logo {
  ..
  background: url(img.png);
  ..
}
```

---

**EDIT (additional tips from another user)**

When running the flask application you will be able to see in the terminal the get requests made by the flask application for the specific html template rendered.

For example,

127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2023 11:35:43] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -

AND

127.0.0.1 - - [02/Feb/2023 11:35:43] "GET /static/css/background_picture.jpeg HTTP/1.1" 200 -

If you get a HTTP 400 response it means that it did try and look for a picture in that specified location but could not find a picture. This can guide you to move your picture to the right location.

You can also on your flask app change the static_folder property to change its base for looking for files.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have overcome this issue in the past is to hard-code the image into the HTML page/template. For example;

```
<div id="image" style="background:url(/static/images/image_of_something.jpg) center / cover no-repeat;"></div>
```

You can then style the image by ID or class further in your style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Remove both `static_url_path` and `static_folder`

In your first line you have:

`app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static/', static_folder='/static/')`

If I remove the trailing slash in `static_url_path='/static/'` and remove the leading slash or both slashes from `static_folder='/static/'` then it works for me.

But since those are the [defaults](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask), I would simply remove both of them.

This works for me:

/main.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(5000)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

/templates/index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-12 bg-logo">
        col 1
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

/static/main.css

```
.bg-logo{
  background: url({{ url_for ('static', filename = '/static/img.png') }});
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I did so and used `app = Flask(__name__)` and also used on my CSS file: `background: url(img.png)`  and doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I also tried on my HTML what I found online on the CSS link `href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}"` and this didn't work either